# Stop making drops/droppings

Tags: vocabulary

When a baby eats food, he might drop lots of food. Can these drops be called droppings? If not, what is the appropriate term:

Stop making drops/droppings?

Comment: Did you do any research on these words, or find evidence they were used this way? I ask because of [*droppings*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/droppings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Droppings* is a term used to mean excrement, especially from a bird or animal.  Recommend to not use this term to describe food a baby drops.

*Bits of food* is probably the best way to describe that.  To tell someone to stop dropping food, say *Stop dropping your food.*  *Stop making a mess* works as well, as dropping food is usually messy.